# Wrapping selecting text in enclosing characters in Emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editor, textmate

In Textmate I can wrap enclosing characters ('(', '[', '"', etc.) around text by selecting it and hitting the opening character.  For example, if I select `word` and hit `(`, it will become `(word)`.  What does Emacs call this feature and how do I enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Autopair](https://github.com/joaotavora/autopair) is the best one of these tools

Comment: "In Emacs 24.4, electric-pair-mode minor-mode is much improved and actually supersedes autopair in functionality and general all-around Emacs integration, and I recommend you use it instead." from provided link

Answer (score 30):

For parens you can do <kbd>M-(</kbd>.  For brackets/braces/quotes you could do:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'insert-pair)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-{") 'insert-pair)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-\"") 'insert-pair)
```

Note that if you don't have a region highlighted, it will just insert the pair of whatevers and put the cursor in between them.  Also handy for deleting matching whatevers is

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-)") 'delete-pair)
```

**EDIT:**

Good point in the comments about overriding `backward-paragraph`.  You could bind it to <kbd>C-{</kbd>, which might interfere with something in a major mode.  `insert-pair` takes the last key and does a lookup to see what pair to insert, so if you don't want to bind it to <kbd>something-{</kbd> you could bind to this function instead:

```
(defun my-insert-braces ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (insert-pair 1 ?{ ?})
    (insert "{}")
    (backward-char)))
```

Comment: Only issue is that `M-{` can no longer be used for backward-paragraph =)

Comment: Interesting bug/weird behaviour: if I enable`(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'insert-pair)`
then emacs inserst escape character garbage whenever I perform a mouse action (but this is only the case for `'M-['`)

Answer (score 8):

Since Emacs 24.1(released 2012-06). 
Put this in your emacs init: (electric-pair-mode 1).
Now If you select a word and hit (, it will become (word). Same for ", [, { etc.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer now.

Answer (score 7):

I use http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit. M-( does exactly this.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at [wrap-region](http://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region).

Answer (score 5):

I'd take a look also at skeleton-mode 
http://ggorjan.blogspot.com/2007/05/skeleton-pair-mode-in-emacs.html

It's very flexible expecially for parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

There is textmate-mode.

From Emacswiki:

See textmate-mode for an attempt of having the TextMate behaviour for parenthesis and quotes (auto-closing, overwriting, smart delete).

http://code.google.com/p/emacs-textmate/

Answer (score 2):

There's now [Corral](https://github.com/nivekuil/corral) as well. Its "do what I mean" behavior makes this process a lot faster than manually selecting the text and hitting the key.

(disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 1):

If you use smartparens just select the text and then type the pair. [Smartparens wiki: Wrapping](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Wrapping)