# Bracket selected text in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to use Emacs for simple text annotation. Is there a command which surrounds a selected region of text with brackets or other characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping selecting text in enclosing characters in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951797/wrapping-selecting-text-in-enclosing-characters-in-emacs)

Comment: Agreed. I'll delete this question shortly. Thank you for the link.

Comment: I can't delete the question as answers exist, but I've flagged it as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a standard emacs command to do this, but this one should do the trick:

```lisp
(defun surround-brackets ()
  "Surround current region with brackets"
  (interactive)
  (when (use-region-p)
    (save-excursion
      (let ((beg (region-beginning))
            (end (region-end)))
        (goto-char end)
        (insert "]")
        (goto-char beg)
        (insert "[")))))
```

**EDIT** As noted in the comments, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2951797/1225607) proposes the following solution, which is much simpler but requires you to use a key binding ending with `[`

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'insert-pair)
```

Answer (score 4):

The most structured and flexible way to do this is with [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/).  I
would say it has become the canonical solution for inserting paired delimiters
and wrapping content in paired delimiters.

Joao (`autopair`'s author) has also written [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet), which is a very
popular templating library in Emacs.  `yasnippet` can be used to wrap
region in arbitrary text.

Both libraries model their behaviour on Textmate.